# Better way to escape braces in E4X?

Tags: javascript, xml, escaping, e4x

I have some XML I'm generating with `{}` characters, which are of course used for substitution.

It's hard to find any info on this: MDC is usually great documentation, but it doesn't mention anything about how to put brace literals in an E4X expression.

I finally found someone who had an answer: escape `{` `}` as `&#x7B;` `&#x7D;`.  But it's really awkward to use.  Is there any other way?

Comment: Your XML structure sounds rather broken if you have tag/attribute names that are to be substituted...

Comment: poke: I'm not sure why that's "broken", but I also never said that's what I'm doing.  E4X allows brace substitution basically anywhere.

Comment: Then could you maybe show an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: He's trying to do something like this: `var xml:XML = <something>{this text is in braces}</something>;` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the cleanest method I can see is to substitute the braces in!

```
var text:String = "some {text} with {braces}";
var xml:XML = <something>{text}</something>;
```

Comment: This is so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it!  Nice.